# Use XREADGROUP to get the id specified

Tags: redis, redis-streams

I'm wondering if there is a command or parameter with which I can get the message for the RecordId specified e.g.

```
XREADGROUP GROUP mygroup myconsumer COUNT 1 STREAMS mystream 12345-0
```

I want the message with the ID 12345-0, but it seems I get the first message after 12345-0.

I cannot use XRANGE since it doesn't update the deliveryCount and lastDeliveryTime and it doesn't seem to understand the concept of consumer groups.

I'm also aware of

```
XREADGROUP GROUP mygroup myconsumer STREAMS mystream 0
```

which gives me all pending messages, but this would update the deliveryCount for all messages and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis itself doesn't provide the function you ask for. So instead you might have to
use something like

XREADGROUP GROUP mygroup myconsumer COUNT 1 STREAMS mystream 12344-99999

instead of "12345-0"

The entry id returned by Redis Stream is in the format of *millisecondsTime-sequenceNumber*.
Since it's unlikely you insert 99999 items in one milisecond, you can be sure that you get the correct item.

Comment: I don't like it, but it is probably the best bet for now.